How to Make Full-Width Items in a Container with Padding in CSS?
I'm trying to create a layout where blue and white rectangles take the full width of the screen while keeping a padding inside the container. Here is my HTML and CSS code:
The problem is that the .item elements are not taking the full width of the container because of the padding. How can I make these items take the full width of the screen while keeping the container's padding?


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>




https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

What is the use of padding, if you want to use the full width?
If not required, remove the padding.

Then add the "container" class dynamically based on the situations. Whenever padding is required bind the "container" class otherwise not.

Here's one way you can do it:


* {box-sizing: border-box;}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  clip-path: inset(0 -100vmax);
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax blue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax white;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>



